# "ZooKeeper exists failed after 4 attempts" when launching Hbase

Tags: hadoop

When launching Hbase I have the following error

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/hbase-1.2.6/bin$ ./hbase shell
2017-11-30 17:26:42,137 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2017-11-30 17:26:59,588 ERROR [main] zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper exists failed after 4 attempts
2017-11-30 17:26:59,589 WARN  [main] zookeeper.ZKUtil: hconnection-0x10823d720x0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Unable to set watcher on znode (/hbase/hbaseid)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1045)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.checkExists(ZKUtil.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionManager.java:905)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:648)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:450)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeStaticDirect(JavaMethod.java:362)
    at org.jruby.java.invokers.StaticMethodInvoker.call(StaticMethodInvoker.java:58)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:312)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:169)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    at org.jruby.ast.InstAsgnNode.interpret(InstAsgnNode.java:95)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:169)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:191)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:302)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:144)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:148)
    at org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:822)
    at org.jruby.RubyClass$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$i$newInstance.gen:65535)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodZeroOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:249)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:292)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:135)
    at home.mike.hbase_minus_1_dot_2_dot_6.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirb.__file__(/home/mike/hbase-1.2.6/bin/../bin/hirb.rb:131)
    at home.mike.hbase_minus_1_dot_2_dot_6.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirb.load(/home/mike/hbase-1.2.6/bin/../bin/hirb.rb)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:697)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:690)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runNormally(Ruby.java:597)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runFromMain(Ruby.java:446)
    at org.jruby.Main.doRunFromMain(Main.java:369)
    at org.jruby.Main.internalRun(Main.java:258)
    at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:224)
    at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:208)
    at org.jruby.Main.main(Main.java:188)
2017-11-30 17:26:59,596 ERROR [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher: hconnection-0x10823d720x0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Received unexpected KeeperException, re-throwing exception
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1045)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:220)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.checkExists(ZKUtil.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionManager.java:905)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:648)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:450)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeStaticDirect(JavaMethod.java:362)
    at org.jruby.java.invokers.StaticMethodInvoker.call(StaticMethodInvoker.java:58)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:312)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:169)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    at org.jruby.ast.InstAsgnNode.interpret(InstAsgnNode.java:95)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:169)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:191)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:302)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:144)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:148)
    at org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:822)
    at org.jruby.RubyClass$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$i$newInstance.gen:65535)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodZeroOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:249)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:292)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:135)
    at home.mike.hbase_minus_1_dot_2_dot_6.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirb.__file__(/home/mike/hbase-1.2.6/bin/../bin/hirb.rb:131)
    at home.mike.hbase_minus_1_dot_2_dot_6.bin.$_dot_dot_.bin.hirb.load(/home/mike/hbase-1.2.6/bin/../bin/hirb.rb)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:697)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:690)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runNormally(Ruby.java:597)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.runFromMain(Ruby.java:446)
    at org.jruby.Main.doRunFromMain(Main.java:369)
    at org.jruby.Main.internalRun(Main.java:258)
    at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:224)
    at org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:208)
    at org.jruby.Main.main(Main.java:188)
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 1.2.6, rUnknown, Mon May 29 02:25:32 CDT 2017
```

Yet I did the advised settings Apache gave in order to make the data persitent 
I tried to run a `status`and it gave me back :

```
2017-11-30 17:26:15,464 ERROR [main] client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Can't get connection to ZooKeeper: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase
```

I found [a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674331/hbase-error-zookeeper-exists-failed-after-3-retiries) which states that the error indicates that zookeeper quorum is not running - most probable cause can be some inconsistency with your zookeeper.quorum setting in `conf/hbase-site.xml` but it didn't helped  my `conf/hbase-side.xml` file looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///DataHbase/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/DataHbase/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error in dev environment, then I added `export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true` to conf/hbase-env.sh and it started working for me. Source - https://askubuntu.com/a/599094 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/22664366